# Am I doing these jQuery resets properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few divs that display different images when clicked and then fade back after 5 seconds. Only I want this number to get reset each time a div is clicked. Below is the code I've tried to use, but it doesn't work. It fades out after five seconds of the first click. I can't make it reset on each new click.

```
var showServicesDelay = function() {
            timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function () {
                    jQuery(".services-inner").css({"opacity": "0.5"});
                jQuery(".insignia-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});
                jQuery(".insignia-inner-text").css({"opacity": "1"});
                hideAll();
        }, 5000);       
    };

    var showMilitaryKit = function() {
        jQuery(".military-kit-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

        clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
};

var showProperty = function() {
        jQuery(".property-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

        clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);    
};

var showHomeContents = function() {
        jQuery(".home-contents-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

        clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
};

// military kit
    jQuery(".military-kit-hover").click(function() {        
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showMilitaryKit();
        showServicesDelay();
    });

// property
    jQuery(".property-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showProperty();
        showServicesDelay();
    }); 

// home contents
    jQuery(".home-contents-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showHomeContents();
        showServicesDelay();
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: here's the working jsFiddle for my issue. http://jsfiddle.net/Cb4wB/1/ At the moment none of the services images disappear.

I need to make it so they disappear after five seconds, unless an different service has been click, in which case that service will be displayed for five seconds, unless another is clicked, and so on.

Comment: Is timeoutHandle a global variable?

Comment: can you please provide code of functions `hideAll()` and `hideServices()`? Without these two your code is fine, so it is possible that something is happening in there.

Comment: Posting a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/ would really help. Also you could rewrite all this `click` handlers in a [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) manner.

Comment: @melc I have created a working jsFiddle which includes them.

Comment: @Cristy How would I write my click handlers in a DRY manner. Could you give me an example of just one? And I added a jsFiddle above.

Comment: @pappy just add `jQuery(document).ready(function() { var timeoutHandle;` and everything works fine. The timeoutHandle was not defined.http://jsfiddle.net/eA6x6/1/

Comment: Brilliant! So I was on the right track. I just need to read up on global declarations again. If you'd like to post this as an actual answer, I'll give you an upvote and a tick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the code to work as expected it is required to define variable `timeoutHandle`.
Thus you could add a line `var timeoutHandle;` in your code as follows,

http://jsfiddle.net/eA6x6/1/

**js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var timeoutHandle;
// timer
    var servicesTimer = 5000;   

// hide stuff
    var hideServices = function() {
            jQuery(".services-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".insignia-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".insignia-inner-text").css({"opacity": "0"});
    };

    var hideAll = function() {
            jQuery(".military-kit-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".property-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".home-contents-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".travel-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".events-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".adventurous-training-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".personal-injury-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".challenge-pursuits-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".sports-and-tours-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
            jQuery(".winter-sports-inner").css({"opacity": "0"});
    };

    var showServicesDelay = function() {
            timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function () {
                    jQuery(".services-inner").css({"opacity": "0.5"});
                jQuery(".insignia-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});
                jQuery(".insignia-inner-text").css({"opacity": "1"});
                hideAll();
        }, 5000);       
    };

// show stuff
    var showMilitaryKit = function() {
            jQuery(".military-kit-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };

    var showProperty = function() {
            jQuery(".property-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);    
    };

    var showHomeContents = function() {
            jQuery(".home-contents-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };

    var showTravel = function() {
            jQuery(".travel-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };

    var showEvents = function() {
            jQuery(".events-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };

    var showAdventurousTraining = function() {
            jQuery(".adventurous-training-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };

    var showPersonalInjury = function() {
            jQuery(".personal-injury-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };

    var showChallengePursuits = function() {
            jQuery(".challenge-pursuits-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };

    var showSportsAndTours = function() {
            jQuery(".sports-and-tours-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };

    var showWinterSports = function() {
            jQuery(".winter-sports-inner").css({"opacity": "1"});

            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    };


// military kit
    jQuery(".military-kit-hover").click(function() {        
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showMilitaryKit();
        showServicesDelay();
    });

// property
    jQuery(".property-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showProperty();
        showServicesDelay();
    }); 

// home contents
    jQuery(".home-contents-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showHomeContents();
        showServicesDelay();
    }); 

// travel
    jQuery(".travel-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showTravel();
        showServicesDelay();
    }); 

// events
    jQuery(".events-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showEvents();
        showServicesDelay();
    }); 

// adventurous training
    jQuery(".adventurous-training-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showAdventurousTraining();
        showServicesDelay();
    }); 

// personal injury
    jQuery(".personal-injury-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showPersonalInjury();
        showServicesDelay();
    }); 

// challenge pursuits
    jQuery(".challenge-pursuits-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showChallengePursuits();
        showServicesDelay();
    }); 

// sports
    jQuery(".sports-and-tours-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showSportsAndTours();
        showServicesDelay();
    }); 

// winter sports
    jQuery(".winter-sports-hover").click(function() {
        hideAll();
        hideServices();
        showWinterSports();
        showServicesDelay();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the global namespace pollution I see here ( too much confusion ), I suggest using jQuery's Deferred Objects or alternatively jQuery's Callbacks. In terms of actions, you can redefine your code by keeping tasks separated. Basically, an action will take place only when another action has finished its task.

[Documentation on Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)